# How to reload uipageviewcontroller after data download complete to consider new data. Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

```
setViewControllers(controllers, direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Is now working when the data download completion is triggered.

```
pageViewController.dataSource = nil
pageViewController.dataSource = self
```

As suggested on some posts is not working either.

Comment: Have you tried to put your datasource update in the main thread?

Comment: No, but How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this in `didFinishAnimating`after changing the set of pages:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    pageViewController.dataSource = nil
    pageViewController.dataSource = self
}
```

Comment: Did it but not workig so far. I was expecting a call like uitableview.reloadData() for uipageviewcontroller, but seems not to exist...